# Accessing $args when it is an object when using 'do_action_ref_array' in WordPress?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

I'm trying to write a callback function and hook it to an action hook I have in my plugin. For example,

```
do_action_ref_array( 'my_action', array( &$args ) );
```

And my callback is:

```
function my_callback( &$args ) {
    // Do something.
}
add_action( 'my_action', 'my_callback' );
```

If `$args` were a simple array, lets say `$args = array( 'arg_1', true, 'foo', 'arg_4' )`, then I could access the values with `$args[0]`, `$args[1]` etc.

**My question:** When `$args` is an object, how would I access it in my callback?

After reading the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action_ref_array), I was under the impression `$args[0]->property` would work but it doesn't. However, `$args->property` does work. Hoping someone can explain why?

Comment: you sould be able to access it like any other object in php `$obj->method()` or `$obj->property`. And since objects are always passed by ref, you can drop the `&` at least in the hook

Comment: What if it was `do_action_ref_array( 'my_action', array( &$args, &$args2, &$args3 ) );`?

Comment: depending on how `do_action_ref_array` works you might have to expand your callback to take 3 parameters and then `$obj1->...` and `$obj2->...` - can you elaborate what `$args` in the callback actually is ?

Comment: Thanks, that explains it nicely. I'm OK to expand the callback to take more params. Do you want to post your comments as an answer so I can give you some credit?

Comment: For the record, I was under the impression I had to do something like this (which is wrong): `$args[0]->...` and `$args[1]->...`

Comment: hold on - doc says `do_action_ref_array` does only take and give arrays - see my answer - so this is acutally right

Comment: Humm that's what is confusing me! `$args[0]->...` doesn't work where as `$args->...` works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

after a look at the doc of `do_action_ref_array` if you give it an `array($obj1,$obj2)`

you should be able to acces them like so

```
function my_callback( &$args ) {
    // $args[0] would be $obj1
    $args[0]->propertyX;
    $args[0]->methodY();

    //and so on
}
```

Comment: I read the same in the documentation. But, using `$args[0]->propertyX` inside my callback doesn't work yet using your original suggestion `$args->propertyX` works. I'm confused. Are the docs wrong?

Comment: may be - but without some real code (what is the content of $args, what exactly are you passing in) its hard to tell.

Comment: I'm working with BuddyPress Follow (a WordPress plugin) and to answer your question, I'm passing in a 'follow' object. See [here](https://github.com/r-a-y/buddypress-followers/blob/master/_inc/bp-follow-classes.php#L157) for the exact code I'm working with.